# trying to configure cmake on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cmake

Please help me out with this error when am trying to configure CMake... [am getting this error on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2I9a.png):

[image: error]

```
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:18 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:784 (include)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/projectp/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "E:/projectp/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: It's asking for Qt5. Provide it.